# How to extend Resharper's Find Usage Advanced option?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, resharper

I have to Find usage of a multiple methods in a .NET Web Application.
I know Resharper provides the "Find Usage Advanced" option. But it is for single Method. But I have to use it for multiple methods. Because I have to prepare a list for Multiple Methods references, where are they referred , In which pages they are referred, etc.

Is it possible to extend Resharper's Find Usage Advanced option for Mutiple  Methods?

Comment: Could you add any example of methods are you looking for?

Comment: This is for our custom webservices and DLLs created for our products.

Comment: I meant any example of input-output. Do you need to find methods with exact names from predefined list? Or by Regex? Or by similar signatures?

Comment: Yes. I need to get references for all the methods which are exact match from predefined list. I have no of webservices/DLL with no methods for each.

Comment: That's still unclear for me. However, in case of exact names a search by Regex like `^(.*FooName.*|.*BarName.*)$` may be helpful. You need to check `Use Regular Expressions` checkbox in standard Visual Studio `Find and Replace` window.

Comment: You can easily test and debug a regexp in `Resharper -> Tools -> Validate Regular Expression` window. Or use online tool https://regex101.com/r/3rCTtC/1